# Assign array to array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am playing around with some arrays, and I cannot figure out why this won't work.

```
int numbers[5] = {1, 2, 3};
int values[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
values = numbers;
```

The following error appear:

```
Error   1   error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value c:\users\abc\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\main.cpp 9   1   ConsoleApplication7
```

Why can't I do like that? What does the error mean?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Arrays have a variety of ugly behavior owing to C++'s backward compatibility with C.  One of those behaviors is that arrays are not assignable.  Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

```
#include <array>
...
std::array<int,5> numbers = {1,2,3};
std::array<int,5> values = {};
values = numbers;
```

If, for some reason, you must use arrays, then you will have to copy the elements via a loop, or a function which uses a loop, such as `std::copy`

```
#include <algorithm>
...
int numbers[5] = {1, 2, 3};
int values[5] = {};
std::copy(numbers, numbers + 5, values);
```

As a side note, you may have noticed a difference in the way I initialized the `values` array, simply providing an empty initializer list.  I am relying on a rule from the standard that says that if you provide an initializer list for an aggregate, no matter how partial, all unspecified elements are value initialized.  For integer types, value initialization means initialization to zero.  So these two are exactly equivalent:

```
int values[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int values[5] = {};
```

Comment: Will this work if the array is two dimensional ? numbers[5][10] instead of numbers[5]

Answer (score 8):

You can't assign arrays in C++, it's stupid but it's true. You have to copy the array elements one by one. Or you could use a built in function like `memcpy` or `std::copy`.

Or you could give up on arrays, and use `std::vector` instead. They can be assigned.

Answer (score 4):

Array names are constant not modifiable l-value, you can't modify it.

```
values = numbers; 
// ^
// is array name
```

Read compiler error message: `"error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value"` an l-value is modifiable can be appear at lhs of `=`.

You can assign array name to a pointer, like:

```
int* ptr = numbers;
```

Note: array name is constant but you can modify its content e.g. `value[i] = number[i]` is an valid expression for `0 <= i < 5`.

> Why can't I do like that?

Basically this constrain is imposed by language, internally array name uses as base address and by indexing with base address you can access content continue memory allocated for array. So in C/C++ array names with be appear at lhs not a l-value.

Comment: "Array names are constant not l-value" Names which refer to arrays are lvalues, as all *id-expressions* which refer to functions, variables or data members are lvalues [expr.prim.general]/8. It's a bit tricky: the assignment operator requires a *modifiable* lvalue, but what that is, is not defined in the C++ Standard, only in the C Standard: 6.3.2.1/1 "A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type [...]". So an array is an lvalue, but not a modifiable lvalue, and therefore cannot appear at the lhs of an assignment.

Comment: @DyP yes I understood I should write "Array names are constant not modifiable l-value""

Comment: @DyP similarly `const` `i`  is l-value not modifiable l-value, Thanks to notice now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

values = numbers; 
Because numbers and values are pointers.

```
int numbers[5] = {1, 2, 3};
int values[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
for(int i = 0;i < 5; i ++){
    values[i] = numbers[i];
}
```

Comment: `numbers` and `values` are not pointers, they are arrays.  And I'll preemptively respond to your objections.  Arrays are not pointers (const or otherwise).  Array names are not pointers (const or otherwise).  Arrays are arrays, and array names are sequences of characters used to refer to arrays in source code.

Answer (score 0):

`std::array` is a good idea, but this is also possible:

```
struct arr { int values[5]; };

struct arr a{{1, 2, 3}};
struct arr b{{}};

a = b;
```

Otherwise, use `std::memcpy` or `std::copy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for non-assignability is that C wants to make sure that any pointers to any element in the array would pretty much always remain valid.

Think about vectors that allow dynamic resizing: the older pointers become invalid (horribly) after resizing happens automatically.

PS. With the design philosophy for vectors, the following block works well.

```
vector<int> v = {1, 5, 16, 8};
vector<int> v_2 = {7, 5, 16, 8};
v_2 = v;
```

Comment: "make sure that any pointers to any element in the array would pretty much always remain valid" That wouldn't apply here as he was trying to assign arrays of the same size.