# what is the difference between these two way to assign array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, assign

```
int numList1[10];

int *numList2 = new int[10];
```

I have seen too many solutions from others used the second way to assign array, do they work as the same?

Comment: The first one is on the stack the second one is on the heap and will therefore leak memory unless `delete` is used, but I advise you to read some good C++ learning resource since this is very basic C++

Comment: use std::array for the first one and std::vector for the second one

Comment: Handy reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. In neither case in an array being assigned. In the first an array is being defined. In the second a pointer is being defined and being initialized. [You cannot actually assign an array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962441/assign-array-to-array), but you can with `std::array` and `std::vector`

Comment: thank you for the comments. It is so painful to study c++ from the internet, they always jump to another unknown section suddenly and I can't catch it...