# Why does an std::insert on an std::set of constant-sized arrays not work as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, set, std

I am in a scenario where I need to process a variable-sized array of constant-sized C-strings, namely: I want to know if each of those strings is unique.
I tried using a `std::set`, as uniqueness of its contents is a given (note: I used a single const-sized array here, as errors produced are the same):

```cpp
#include <set>

int main(){
    std::set<wchar_t[4]> sSet;
    const wchar_t[4] text = L":)\0";
    // checking if successful
    // set.insert() returns a pair of <iterator, bool>
    // when used like this
    std::pair<std::set<wchar_t[4]>::iterator, bool> result = \
    sSet.insert(text);
    if(!result.second) std::cout << "Value not unique!";
    return 0;
}
```

The mentioned code crashes in a spectacular manner:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:518:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘construct_at(wchar_t (*&)[4], const wchar_t [4])’
  518 |           std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
(note: I skipped a lot of stack tracing here)
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:96:56: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘wchar_t’ [-fpermissive]
   96 |     -> decltype(::new((void*)0) _Tp(std::declval<_Args>()...))
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
      |                                                        |
      |                                                        const wchar_t*

(a dozen or so notes follow,
some of them are about passing a wrong number of parameters, 
and most are beyond me, see next line)
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_set.h:518:7: note: candidate: ‘std::pair, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Key = wchar_t [4]; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Tp>, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree, std::less, std::allocator >::const_iterator; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key>::other = std::allocator; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<_Key> = __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, wchar_t [4]>::rebind; typename _Alloc::value_type = wchar_t [4]; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = wchar_t [4]]’
  518 |       insert(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~
```

Compiling with MSVC yielded something entirely different:

```
error C3074: an array can only be initialized with an initializer-list
```

(curly bracing, as per error's suggestion, did not work)

As it seems to be an error inside of stdlibs' files, I am curious: what happened here? Approach I've shown works perfectly with sets of types which are not arrays, like `std::set<int>`.
I suspect that I violated the intended syntax, which is `insert(value_type&& value);`, as per [a reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) (note: my target standard is C++11). If so, what have I done incorrectly? I find the error messages inconclusive, and toying around with `std`'s files is yet beyond me.

*I know my initial problem can be solved in various ways, I'm using a vector of vectors for now - I'm still intrigued by this `std::set` behaviour, though.*

Comment: `std::insert` isn't a thing and `wchar_t[4] text = ...;` is not the proper way to declare an array. Also, don't use arrays inside your `std::set`. If you want a fixed size object, use `std::array<wchar_t, 4>`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it: I of course intended a `std::set<type>.insert` there, as shown in example. About the other thing, I missed a `const` there, thanks.
Also, the `std::array<>` approach worked fine, can you please retype it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can edit the question to correct it.

Comment: You can make your code shorter: `const wchar_t[4] text = L":)\0"; const wchar_t[4] key = text;` and find the dupe [Assign array to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962441/assign-array-to-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess this has been more or less answered in the comments, but I think it might be worth pulling it all together to help you on your way.

When declaring a `set` (and other STL containers), the type of the elements in a set needs to be a 'value type', and a C-style array ain't.  But `std::array` is, so, as Ted says, use that instead.

Knowing that, the changes you need to make should be obvious, but, being the pedant that I am, I've made them anyway:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

using wc4 = std::array <wchar_t, 4>;

int main ()
{
    std::set <wc4> sSet;
    wc4 text = { L":)\0" };
    auto result = sSet.insert (text);
    if (!result.second)
        std::cout << "Value not unique!";
}
```

Notes:

1. Your code didn't crash.  It failed to compile.  But yes, C++ compiler error messages can be messy, at best.
2. Use `auto`, when you can.
3. Not sure why you slipped that `\0` in there.  Now you have two.
4. Please make sure you, erm, include all the relevant `#includes`.  It will stand you in good stead later on in your career, if nothing else.  `utility` was missing here (for `std::pair`).
5. *I know my initial problem can be solved in various ways, I'm using a vector of vectors for now* well, we can't see that code, so,

Comment: Many thanks for the advice! I'm learning C++ with previous knowledge of C and I'm not yet fully aware of all the modernisations in place - explicitly null-terminating strings is a habit I need to get rid of. Also `auto` used to be useless, but I'm going to start using it :)

Comment: OK.  `auto` did indeed used to be useless, so they 'repurposed' it in C++11, I believe.  Here is an important resource which should help you on your way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list